# bootstrap navigation border for last-child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the actual bootstrap. I've styled my Bootstrap navigation with `li border-right` but when I use

```
.wrapper .header .navbar.navbar-default .container .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse .nav.navbar-nav li:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
```

}

For the last-child the border is always shown!

What can I do that the `border-right` for the last-child will not be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use border-left instead of border-right and set it to 0 for `li:first-child`

CSS will be like following :

```
.wrapper .header .navbar.navbar-default .container .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse .nav.navbar-nav li { border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC; }

.wrapper .header .navbar.navbar-default .container .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-responsive-collapse .nav.navbar-nav li:first-child {
border-left:0px none;
}
```

Remember that `last-child` selector is never works in IE Lower versions. Instead first-child is works fine with every version of IE and other browsers too.

Also, remeber to put `border-left:0px none` instead just using `border-left:0px`

Comment: Oh, its my passion to solve issues, by the way you can upvoted my answer ;)

Comment: at the moment i can not upvote because i'm a beginner and need more reputation

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should simplify your css path to avoid error.

Then try to use `border-right: none;` instead of 0px like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUY6R/).